# Capturing DBIC exception to prevent script from dying

Tags: perl

I'm running a perl script to update a currently working database with new datasets. Basically, the script receives molecule information as plain text (MDL if you are interested) and performs several chemical properties calculations through a bunch of third party softwares called via system.

The script have never had any problems processing data but the last dataset seems to have some molecules (or at least one, for what it's worth) for which some of the properties make no sense and I end up having truncated data insertions, which lastly causes a DBIC exception. Namely:

```
DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI::_dbh_execute(): DBI Exception: DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Column 'inchi' cannot be null [for Statement "INSERT INTO moldata ( formula, hba, hbd, inchi, inchikey, mol_id, pm, psa, ro3pass, ro5vio, rtb, smiles, xlogp3aa) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )" with ParamValues: 0='I', 1='0', 2='0', 3=undef, 4='XMBWDFGMSWQBCA-YPZZEJLDSA-M', 5=936934, 6='125.00', 7='0', 8=6, 9=0, 10='0', 11='[125I-]', 12='0.86']
```

At this point, the program just dies. I can surely do some workarounds to avoid getting "undefs" in the inserts, but I'd like DBIC to be able to handle them and continue with the inserts while ignoring (and maybe warn me about them later) the bad ones.

What would be the right way to implement a try/catch scenario in perl for DBIC transactions?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show the code that does the create on the resultset. One of your values is coming back from your calculations as undefined. You will need to look at the program that calculated this inchi and probably also the input data used to calculate it.